# Back Pressure Event 15004 was detected

Tags: windows, exchange, windows-server-2016

I have error 15004 and 15005 on excange server installed machine, resource utilzation is ok (according to zabix), what can cause it except memory and space?

Answer (score 0):

Currently judging from the documentation, the main factors are only the disk space and memory you mentioned. For details, you can continue to refer to this MS DOC.
[Understanding back pressure | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/back-pressure?view=exchserver-2019)

I noticed that your current event has been changed to 15005, and the event type is information is not an error, so the current resource utilization is normal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmJFg.png)